# Getting sum from alias in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my sql code

```
SELECT qty, unitprice, qty * unitprice as Stock FROM item
```

Form this i want to get the SUM of Stock

Comment: Did you try `SUM(qty*unitprice)` by using `group by`.

Comment: yes tried...but it is not working

Comment: Try calculating just the sum using `SELECT SUM(qty*unitprice) as stock FROM item`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what you are asking here. I'm not sure about the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve, but this will bring you `SUM` of all `qty * unitprice` :

```
SELECT qty, unitprice, SUM(qty * unitprice) as Stock FROM item
```

And this is literally bring you `SUM` of `Stock` :

```
SELECT SUM(Stock) as SUM_OF_STOCK
FROM 
    (SELECT qty, unitprice, qty * unitprice as Stock 
     FROM item)
```

If none of above query fit your needs, I think you really need to edit the question and elaborate more on what you are trying achieve.